# How to add help documentation on a method in a C# dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, view-helpers, code-documentation

I want to add help/documentation text to a library that I am building in C#. I am using  /// to create the tags  and this works just fine when I use methods of my library in my lirary proyect. For example:

if my library have 2 classes Car and Person, if a I type in Person

```
Car.StartEngi
```

the auto complete of VS will suggest to use StartEngine methos and I will see the summary that for the method, fro example "This method will start the engine of the car".

But the issue comes when I compile and try to reference the dll on a separate solution. In the new solution I have already add the corresponding reference and using statement but when I write

```
Car.StartEngi
```

VS will indeed recommend to use StartEngine BUT I can not see the documentation. Does anyone know why? Do I need to add some parameter when I build the library?

P.D All the methods in the library that generates the dll are public

Comment: Step back for a moment. What exactly does "this method will start the engine of the car" tell you that `car.StartEngine()` doesn't tell you? Your "documentation" serves no purpose here.

Comment: You need to create the documentation XML file. The compiler has a [option for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3260k4x7.aspx), which should be enabled in the corresponding [Visual Studio settings page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kb4wyys2(v=vs.100).aspx) (project properties > build > output > XML documentation file).

Comment: @DavidArno, I'm assuming this is just a simplified example and OP isn't actually trying to start the engine of a car...

Comment: Yes you are right this was just a simplified example :)  RogerN and @Jordão just wrote the wirte question at the same time :) Thanks A lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Build page of your project settings you need to turn on "XML documentation file".  If you copy the XML documentation file along with your assembly then you should be able to see the documentation in other projects.